# Regular expression. Regular or Irregular?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I just want to get a second opionion on these expression and whether they are irregular or regular.

`{0^n 1^m | n >= m >=0}`   REGULAR

`{0^n 1^m | n,m >=0}*` REGULAR

`{0^n 0^n | n>=0}` IRREGULAR

can anyone confirm that this is true?

Comment: Seems like you should tag this as homework.

Comment: oh sorry im new i didnt know there was a hw tag. can u confirm this or are u just here to critisize me for being ignorant to the way the site works?

Comment: You talk about an M which is never used.

Comment: I think you need to proofread your questions.

Comment: Why are you refering to `m` when you only have `n`s? I don't see why the third one is irregular. I assume you mean 'n' 0s followed by another 'n' zeros, or just 'm` zeros, where m = 2n, which is clearly regular.

Comment: I wasn't criticizing, I was assuming that this is homework and leaving room for the possibility that I was wrong. If indeed it's homework, it should have the tag (as you've since added).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{0^n 1^m | n >= m >=0}` Since an FSM cannot keep track of what n was in order to ensure n>=m, an FSM cannot represent the expression.

`{0^n 1^m | n,m >=0}*` -- an FSM can seem to represent this but there are problems. Unlike the first problem, n and m are unrelated to one another so no FSM creation issues. The problem is that n and m must remain the same for multiple passes through the machine. Again, since there's no memory, this isn't possible.

`{0^n 0^n | n>=0}` -- this is simple with an FSM as well. It looks much like the 2nd problem's FSM. The RE is `(00)*`

Comment: I believe you can create a FSM for `{0^n 1^m | n,m >=0}*` as we can construct a NFA for `0^n` and we can construct a NFA for `1^m`. Therefore though concatanation we can construct a NFA for `0^n 1^m` and thus it is simple to apply a kleene closure to our concatanation. It seems that we can represent this as the RE `(0|1)*`

Comment: @Bodyloss - if it were not for the kleene star on the end, you would be correct. The problem is that when you loop from the 2nd FA (1^m) back to the first, the values for n and m must remain the same as they were on the first pass through the machine -- and without a memory, this isn't possible.

Comment: Oh, by saying `n,m >= 0` does that mean also that `n = m` as we pass though the machine? As if not then surely you can construct `A*` where `A = {0^n 1^m | n,m >= 0}` using Thompsons construction?

Comment: It isn't saying n = m (if that were the case there would only be one variable). It's saying that whatever values they are, they are constant for each pass through the machine's body in a single execution of the machine. Lets say the input string is to be 001001; the machine you suggested can pass that easily. However, the target machine must reject 00101 (and allow 00110011 but reject 001101, for example).